# Display my rs.open query on the screen

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I want to know how to print my query from an rs.open.

I know it's probably a silly question but I was trying like this:

```
rs.open "Select * from employees" & condition & " AND " & condition2 & condition3 & " Order by " & order, con, 3, 1
```

Trying to do a response.write from the rs

```
Response.Write(rs)
```

But it's not working, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered a way to print the rs without saving it on a variable, just if anyone else needs it.

We can display the recordset data using `source` it returns a String value that indicates the data source of the Recordset object.

Just using it this way:

```
response.Write(rs.source)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the *SQL query*, you can't just print the recordset.

Instead, you need to save the SQL query in a variable and print *that*.

Pseudocode because I'm writing this on my phone and don't remember the right syntax to declare variables in ASP Classic:

```
SQL = "select * from ..."
rs.open SQL, con, 3, 1
Response.write(SQL)
```

Comment: So there's no way to print it without saving the query in a variable? :(
Well thanks for the answer! :)